# Vector space of differential forms on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

Why is the space of differential forms on a curve (defined on the fraction field of the coordinate ring) a one-dimensional vector space over the function field of the curve?
(I am uncomfortable with most elements of field theory such as transcendence basis or separability so please avoid using them in the answer)
Also, what is an analogous statement of this in differential geometry?

Comment: The reason is precisely because the field of functions has transcendence degree one over the ground field. If you are not  comfortable with that, you should make yourself comfortable!

Comment: In differential geometry there is no field of functions, so you get blocked there... What is true is that the forms on a curve are a free module over the ring of smooth functions of rank one (because curves are parallelizable)